# Use return of function directly without a variable

Tags: php, function, pdo, return, bind

Sorry for my english, can't find the correct words on Google to find why it acts like this. Must be very easy to solve!

I'm using PHP 7 and I want to use the return provided by a function for a query (bind it). If I call directly the function in my bind function, it returns nothing. If I call it outside, like $var = function($a) and use $var into the bind function, it works.

I don't get why I can't use directly the function? If I do this in the parameters of a function (like function getID($this->getName(1))) it works. why it doesn't here? The code:

**Doesn't work**

```
        $this->bdd->query("UPDATE stats_of_the_days
                            SET winner_firstsolves = :winner_fs
                            WHERE id = :stat_id");

        $this->bdd->bind("winner_fs", $this->getTodayWinnerFs($winnerID), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->bdd->bind("stat_id", $statID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $this->bdd->execute();
```

**Works (using a variable to call/store the function/return)**

```
    $var = $this->getTodayWinnerFs($winnerID);

    $this->bdd->query("UPDATE stats_of_the_days
                        SET winner_firstsolves = :winner_fs
                        WHERE id = :stat_id");

    $this->bdd->bind("winner_fs", $var, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $this->bdd->bind("stat_id", $statID, PDO::PARAM_INT);


    $this->bdd->execute();
```

**The function is pretty basic**

```
public function getTodayWinnerFs($userID)
    {
      // query stuff
      return $this->bdd->resultObj()->Wins;
    }
```

**Example of return of the function**

```
var_dump($this->getTodayWinnerFs(494));
// string(2) "13"
```

**The "bind" function from my db pdo class**

```
        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
        {
            if (is_null($type)) {
                switch (true) {
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }
            $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is because the method `getTodayWinnerFs()` and the main one are sharing `$this->bdd` and in the wrong call it is in a different status, I think you should stick to the working example and don't make function calls within function calls, it will make it harder to read.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! It just that I like to get the less lines as possible in my code, which leads to this kind of behavior & errors unfortunately... (I have to bind 7 variables for this query).

Comment: I made a bindArray function, bind all the parameters in an array before calling $this->bdd->query(), works pretty well!

Comment: @kinoute you only patched this issue, but wrong design will backfire again.

Comment: @YourCommonSense but I don't understand how vikkio's answer is correct when mine is not? Both are calling the functions before the query() function.

mine:

`$params = array("blabla" => $this->getName(), "ok" => $this->getID());

$this->bdd->query(...);

$this->bdd->bindArray($params);`

him:
`$var = $this->getName();

$this->bdd->query(...);

$this->bdd->bind("blabla", $var);`